# How do you make a custom payload in Dialogflow using facebook loop back to a previous intent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, payload

I have a conversation flow set up to work as a chatbot using Dialogflow that when you reach the end of the conversation you can loop back round to the start of the flow or end the conversation. At the loop back stage we currently have this in the payload:

```
{
  "type": "backTo",
  "intent": "hello"
}
```

I thought that the hello would be the trigger to an earlier intent and start the flow again.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Intents are based on *what the user does*. So it doesn't really make sense to say that your code is triggering an earlier Intent.

Instead, just send back a reply indicating you're starting over and don't end the conversation. If appropriate, you can also set the context so an earlier Intent that has this as the Input Context matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should either set `output context` for this intent which will match to the `input context` as **@Prisoner** said.
Or you can invoke the intent programmatically using the `events`.